# Bypass google automated query scurity check

Tags: python, request, google-drive-api

i have a list of google drive file links about 300 pdf files which i have to download

so what i am trying to do is using pythons request library i am requesting to google server and getting the files.

after 30 to 36 files download google blocks my requests and return

> We're sorry...... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now.

i am using the following code

```
import requests
def download_file_from_google_drive(id, destination):
    URL = "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download"

    session = requests.Session()

    response = session.get(URL, params = { 'id' : id }, stream = True)
    if response.status_code!=200:
        print(response.status_code)
        return response.status_code
    print('downloading '+ destination)
    token = get_confirm_token(response)
    if token:
        params = { 'id' : id, 'confirm' : token }
        response = session.get(URL, params = params, stream = True)

    save_response_content(response, destination)    

def get_confirm_token(response):
    for key, value in response.cookies.items():
        if key.startswith('download_warning'):
            return value

    return None

def save_response_content(response, destination):
    CHUNK_SIZE = 32768

    with open(destination, "wb") as f:
        i = 0
        for chunk in response.iter_content(CHUNK_SIZE):
            print(str(i)+'%')
            i = i+1
            if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                f.write(chunk)
    print('downloaded '+ destination)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_id = 'file id'
    destination = file_id+'.pdf'
    download_file_from_google_drive(file_id, destination)
```

i am iterating `download_file_from_google_drive` this function using my list

so can i bypass the security check

i tried using vpn which changes my ip address but nothing works.

after about 1hour downloading restart

Comment: Could we download the folder as a zip and process them from your local storage? Or if you need them in the cloud why not use a google cloud bucket?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @damianr13 no i don't have the access to the folder i must download them one by one

Comment: Wild guess these links are share with me links.  Google really doesnt want you doing this they are tracking you by your IP address probably.  Use the Google drive api and get access, dont try to use share with me links programmatically its not intended for this purpose.